# 3D model was not changed at runtime while using obb in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I was working AR android application development using `ARCore` sdk and unity3d Engine.I have a 30 3d models and have 2 scenes.One scene is like splash scene and second scene is AR Scene which have 30 models.i was splitted the apk using split into binary method in unity.My obb size is 396mb and apk size is 22mp so i was exported it to android studio project and import the project into android studio and set needed requirements for run the project.Copy the obb file into android/obb/directory.Everything works fine but i was used to change the 3d model at runtime using `UnityPlayer`.`UnitySendMessage` method and also put the method for changing models in C# Script but the model was not changed.

Without obb creation the model was changed at runtime.How can i change the model at runtime with obb files?

Answer (score 1):

Putting your obb in Android/obb is not enough you need to follow this scheme [Link Here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files).

### Explanation

Basically you need to put your obb in Android/obb/your-package-name/
And your obb must also follow this naming scheme "main.versionCode.your-package-name.obb" without this Unity can not automatically find your obb file.

Comment: Thank you for your response..I have fixed the problem